# Want to show Update Progress control on top of ModalPopExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender, updateprogress

I have a content page with an Update Panel and a Update Progress controls. The Update Progress control is properly displayed when the page posts back. I have now added a Modal Popup Extender to the page. When a post back is fired from the Modal Popup Extender, the Update Progress control is displayed, but underneath the Modal Popup Extender.

How can I force the Update Progress control to appear on top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Increase the `z-index` of the `UpdateProgress` via CSS.

```
.progress
{
    z-index: 100002 !important;
}
```

Edit: Added [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Zohaib: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487977/284240), the default z-index of a ModalPopupExtender is 100001. So it should be sufficient to use 100002 ;)